# SqlException.Message duplicated when calling sqlserver stored proc

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlexception, executenonquery

I have a stored procedure that gives a friendly enough error that I want to show to the users but when I call it from .net it comes out twice. When I call the proc from sql server management studio it only comes out once.

Here is a cutdown version of the stored proc:

```
ALTER PROC [Production].[spDoSomething] (
            @PassedID int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorString nvarchar(500);
    BEGIN TRY
        ...
        RAISERROR('Bad things are happening.', 11 /*severity*/, 1 /*state*/);
        ...
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ErrorString = 'Error found:' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        PRINT @ErrorString;
        RAISERROR(@ErrorString, 11 /*severity*/, 1 /*state*/);
    END CATCH
END
```

I call this in some c# code using `ExecuteNonQuery()` of a `System.Data.SqlClient.SQLCommand` object then I catch a `System.Data.SqlClient.SQLException` but the Message contains

> "Error: Found Bad things are happening.\nError Found: Bad things are happening."

Does anyone know a reason why it comes out twice?

This is on sql server 2008 and .net 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please comment the "PRINT @ErrorString;" statement.
When SQL Engine throws an error, it would displays all the messages are available in the message stack.

**Reason:**

Try to run below code snap.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ErrorHandler

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @ErrorString nvarchar(500);
    BEGIN TRY
        RAISERROR('Bad things are happening.', 11 /*severity*/, 1 /*state*/);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ErrorString = 'Error found:' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        PRINT @ErrorString;
        PRINT 'Stack overflow'
        RAISERROR(@ErrorString, 11 /*severity*/, 1 /*state*/);
    END CATCH
END
GO

EXEC ErrorHandler
```

SQL engine generates 3 messages;

```
1. 1st for PRINT @ErrorString;

2. 2nd for PRINT 'Stack overflow'

3. 3rd for RAISERROR(@ErrorString, 11 /*severity*/, 1 /*state*/);
```

Comment: I have duplicated messages when THROW is executed in SQL Server SP. I don't have prints. Anyway in C# I just check duplication in message, if any, then I strip it and show to the user just resulting message without duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting I deleted the print statement and it turns out that the print statements get passed through as part of the exception message.